# How do I remove lines from a string begins with specific string in Lua?

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

How do I remove lines from a string begins with another string in Lua ? For instance i want to remove all line from string `result` begins with the word `<Table`. This is the code I've written so far:

```
for line in result:gmatch"<Table [^\n]*" do line = "" end
```

Comment: If it is HTML you are parsing, don't use lua-patterns. Try [HTML-parser](https://github.com/wscherphof/lua-htmlparser)

Comment: It is an XML With namespaces, i am using corona SDK.

Comment: Probably not a good idea to use patterns for that. Lua patterns are less powerful than regular expressions and [regular expressions cannot be used to parse XHTML and Co.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

Comment: I recommend using a real [xml parser](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2011/07/29/how-to-use-xml-files-in-corona/) for parsing your input file. String manipulation won't take into account `&` escapes, `<!--` comments, whiletespace `< Table`, and so on. (Similarly, I also highly recommend using a XML-aware tool to generate your XML, for similar reasons).

Comment: Do you know any xml parser to handle this kind of xml ( http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=P3DxHB8x ) ? P.S. parser must work with corona sdk.

Answer (score 1):

`string.gmtach` is used to get all occurrences of a pattern. For replacing certain pattern, you need to use `string.gsub`.

Another problem is your pattern `<Table [^\n]*` will match all line containing the word `<Table`, not just begins with it.

Lua pattern doesn't support beginning of line anchor, this almost works:

```
local str = result:gsub("\n<Table [^\n]*", "")
```

except that it will miss on the first line. My solution is using a second run to test the first line:

```
local str1 = result:gsub("\n<Table [^\n]*", "")
local str2 = str1:gsub("^<Table [^\n]*\n", "")
```

Comment: `local str = ('\n'..result):gsub("\n<Table [^\n]*", ""):sub(2)`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Aha, that's clever and elegant.

Comment: Lua pattern does support beginning of line anchor.

Comment: @AlexanderAltshuler Which is ...?

Answer (score 1):

The [LPEG](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) library is perfect
for this kind of task.
Just write a function to create custom line strippers:

```
local mk_striplines
do
  local lpeg      = require "lpeg"
  local P         = lpeg.P
  local Cs        = lpeg.Cs
  local lpegmatch = lpeg.match

  local eol       = P"\n\r" + P"\r\n" + P"\n" + P"\t"
  local eof       = P(-1)
  local linerest  = (1 - eol)^1 * (eol + eof) + eol

  mk_striplines = function (pat)
    pat               = P (pat)
    local matchline   = pat * linerest
    local striplines  = Cs (((matchline / "") + linerest)^1)
    return function (str)
      return lpegmatch (striplines, str)
    end
  end
end
```

Note that the argument to `mk_striplines()` may be a string or a
pattern.
Thus the result is very flexible:
`mk_striplines (P"<Table" + P"</Table>")` would create a stripper
that drops lines with two different patterns.
`mk_striplines (P"x" * P"y"^0)` drops each line starting with an
`x` followed by any number of `y`’s  -- you get the idea.

Usage example:

```
local linestripper = mk_striplines "foo"

local test = [[
foo lorem ipsum
bar baz
buzz
foo bar
xyzzy
]]

print (linestripper (test))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers provide good solutions to actually stripping lines from a string, but don't address why your code is failing to do that.

Reformatting for clarity, you wrote:

```
for line in result:gmatch"<Table [^\n]*" do 
    line = "" 
end
```

The first part is a reasonable way to iterate over `result` and extract all spans of text that begin with `<Table` and continue up to but not including the next newline character. The iterator returned by `gmatch` returns a *copy* of the matching text on each call, and the local variable `line` holds that copy for the body of the `for` loop.

Since the matching text is copied to `line`, changes made to `line` are not and cannot modifying the actual text stored in `result`.

This is due to a more fundamental property of Lua strings. All strings in Lua are immutable. Once stored, they cannot be changed. Variables holding strings are actually holding a pointer into the internal table of reference counted immutable strings, which permits only two operations: internalization of a new string, and deletion of an internalized string with no remaining references.

So any approach to editing the content of the string stored in `result` is going to require the creation of an entirely new string. Where `string.gmatch` provides an iteration over the content but cannot allow it to be changed, `string.gsub` provides for creation of a new string where all text matching a pattern has been replaced by something new. But even `string.gsub` is not changing the immutable source text; it is creating a new immutable string that is a copy of the old with substitutions made.

Using `gsub` could be as simple as this:

```
result = result:gsub("<Table [^\n]*", "")
```

but that will disclose other defects in the pattern itself. First, and most obviously, nothing requires that the pattern match at only the beginning of the line. Second, the pattern does not include the newline, so it will leave the line present but empty.

All of that can be refined by careful and clever use of the pattern library. But it doesn't change the fact that you are starting with XML text and are not handling it with XML aware tools. In that case, any approach based on pattern matching or even regular expressions is likely to end in tears.

Comment: Very useful answer, can you suggest me an xml parser in lua to handle that kind of xml files (http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=P3DxHB8x)? Xml parser must not using dll files, because i want to use it for corona sdk.

Comment: See the [Lua User's Wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaXml) for a page devoted to XML parsers for Lua. There are several pure Lua solutions, and several that bind external libraries. That said, I would tend to expect that there is already a well-known XML parser as part of or commonly used with Corona, but not being a Corona user, I don't know what it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
result = result:gsub('%f[^\n%z]<Table [^\n]*', '')
```

The start of this pattern, `'%f[^\n%z]`, is a *frontier pattern* which will match any transition from either a newline or zero character to another character, and for frontier patterns the pre-first character counts as a zero character. In other words, using that prefix allows the rest of the pattern to match at either the first line or any other start-of-line.

Reference: [the Lua 5.3 manual, section 6.4.1 on string patterns](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6.4.1)